# How to call the name of an element in a list on this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

halfway done through my word search code and I have a very small problem, I have no idea to label each solution. I have to call the word from a list and match it with its direction. I think you could understand it better by looking below.

So here is a snippet of the code:

```
words=['hello','hola','hella','heya','heyo','hill','halo','hall','hail','hay','hale','holy']
rows= ['eahaehh','allehoh','gohloau','rhelloy','iayoyiu','iiaelah','hlhallo']
row_length=len(rows[0])
column_length=len(rows)

for row_number, row in enumerate(rows):
    if any(word in row for word in words):
            print(f"{row} right")

for row_number, row in enumerate(rows):
    candidate = ''.join(reversed(row))
    if any(word in candidate for word in words):
        print(f"{candidate} left")
```

As you can see in the print function I am just printing the whole row and not the actual word itself. I tried adding a for loop before the if statement but it just messed up the entire thing.

The code gives me an output of:

```
rhelloy right
hlhallo right
hohella left
haleaii left
```

Clearly here it  just prints the entire row the word is in. I was kinda hoping to have an output of:

```
hello right
hallo right
hella left
hale left
```

Any thoughts on how to proceed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you need to get the word contained in row, so instead of any you could use [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to retrieve the word:

```
words=['hello','hola','hella','heya','heyo','hill','halo','hall','hail','hay','hale','holy']
rows= ['eahaehh','allehoh','gohloau','rhelloy','iayoyiu','iiaelah','hlhallo']
row_length=len(rows[0])
column_length=len(rows)

for row_number, row in enumerate(rows):
    w = next((word for word in words if word in row), None)
    if w:
        print(f"{w} right")

for row_number, row in enumerate(rows):
    candidate = ''.join(reversed(row))
    w = next((word for word in words if word in candidate), None)
    if w:
        print(f"{w} left")
```

**Output**

```
hello right
hall right
hella left
hale left
```

The next function basically retrieves the **next** element of an iterator, from the documentation:

> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its **next**()
>   method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is
>   exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.

The default value is the one to be used in case the iterator is empty, note that in the example of this answer we are providing a default of `None`.

Comment: Woah, did not know the next function at all. I tried and it works like a charm, but can I ask what the next() do exactly? What are its arguments?

Comment: Wow! Thanks for that answer, one more function to my brain library! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. Note that you have multiple words fitting to the row entries:

```
words=['hello','hola','hella','heya','heyo','hill','halo','hall','hail','hay','hale','holy']
rows= ['eahaehh','allehoh','gohloau','rhelloy','iayoyiu','iiaelah','hlhallo']
row_length=len(rows[0])
column_length=len(rows)

for row_number, row in enumerate(rows):
    for word in words:
        if word in row:
            print(f"{word} right")

for row_number, row in enumerate(rows):
    candidate = ''.join(reversed(row))
    for word in words:
        if word in candidate:
            print(f"{word} left")

# hello right
# hall right
# hella left
# hale left
```

Comment: Hi! This one works too, but which would be better to use in my case this one or @Daniel Mesejo's solution?

Answer (score 0):

change:

```py
    if any(word in row for word in words):
            print(f"{row} right")
```

to

```
    for word in words:
        if word in row:
            print(f"{word} right")
```